# What's the approach to use when developing API with a callback?

Tags: rest, api

What's the approach that should I use to develop an API that receives two moves and return a result (win/lose/draw)?

Scattegories game

Example:

Animal that starts with letter L

Player 1 - move: Lion
Player 2 - move: Lyon

`thegame.com/api/v1/game/1/player/1/move/1`

`thegame.com/api/v1/game/1/player/2/move/1`

- How return the result to the players?
- Should object player wait for the response or ask result?
- What's the best way to develop an API with a callback?
- Any other way to resolve this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plurals are a bit more common, ie:

```
thegame.com/api/v1/games/1/players/1/moves/1
```

I think it's probably more logical for moves to be directly under the game, independent of players:

```
thegame.com/api/v1/games/1/moves/1
```

where each move has an associated player who made the move. This would make it easy to re-run all moves and understand the game history.

For players, their canonical URL would be independent of games

```
thegame.com/api/v1/players/1
```

You can still have a way to access all games for a player and all players for a game, if you like

```
thegame.com/api/v1/players/1/games
thegame.com/api/v1/games/1/players
```

Assuming this is a 2 (or more) player game with humans waiting on each other, you could probably make each client poll the game every few seconds. e.g. if a client has made the latest move, it starts polling the URL `thegame.com/api/v1/games/1?moves_since=123456`. This returns a list of all moves since the timestamp 123456. The timestamp could be the time the last move was made by this user. Once it returns a valid move, the client shows that to the user and waits for them to make their own move. If there are several players, the "game" resource could include a field like "nextMover" to indicate which player is next to make a move.

A more modern way would be to use something like Websockets so the client gets an immediate push from the server when changes occur. It's mostly a similar design but server immediately notifies all clients of updates instead of clients polling.